# Angular Material Selection List Checkboxes do not visibly check

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have an Angular Material 9 selection list bound to an array as in their example.

```
 <mat-selection-list #sendingList [(ngModel)]="selectedSendingFeatures">
      <mat-list-option *ngFor="let item of sending" checkboxPosition="before" [value]="item">
        {{ item }}
      </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
```

`sending` is an array of strings, as in their "shoes" example.

The model updates correctly as I click on checkboxes. But the **checkboxes** themselves do not appear checked.  They are always unchecked.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mark an option as selected us `selected` property

```
 <mat-selection-list #sendingList [(ngModel)]="selectedSendingFeatures">
      <mat-list-option *ngFor="let item of sending" checkboxPosition="before" selected>
        {{ item }}
      </mat-list-option>
 </mat-selection-list>
```

You can further pass a boolean value to make sure it follows your data

```
[selected]="item.isSelected"
```

Comment: but then my items need to be objects, with a `selected` property.  That's not awful, but their example only uses a simple array of strings.  So how are they doing it?

Comment: It doesn't work, anyway.  I updated the model "sending" to be an array of objects with a "label" and "selected" property and used your second example, still no check marks

Comment: For  the second example, item would need to have a label property to display as well. Would share a stackblitz demo in a moment!

Comment: I've got `item.label`, the display works.  the `ngModel` works.  The `sendingList.selectedOptions.selected.length` works.  The check BOX does not check itself.

Comment: This should work https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhkta5?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-selection-example.ts  :)

Comment: thanks.  turns out that's not even needed,  after a great deal of digging i found a CSS bug that was not changing the checkbox background color. Oops!

Comment: Haha! Happens. Btw, do mark this as accepted answer if it happens to answer the original question :D